# Windows Explorer can't handle copying terabytes (TB) of files, what works instead?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'm trying to move 1.6TB of files from one drive to another in Windows 7 x64.  Unfortunately after I begin the job with Windows Explorer, CPU usage goes up to 80-100%.  After an unspecified number of hours, CPU usage drops to zero but no real copying work is done.  I verified this and the amount of time the disk is busy with assorted system monitoring tools.

The unfortunate implication of this is that when I try to use an alternative file manager to move the files, I can tell that said file manager is just asking explorer to move them - the same standard windows 'move' dialog comes up and the same problem results.

I'm trying to get the files moved.  Is there a file manager that handles an operation of this kind without just 'outsourcing' the job to Explorer?

Additional:  Both source and destination drives are Internal SATA formatted as NTFS.  Windows version is Ultimate.

Comment: Stop using the GUI.  Use the CLI.  For examople Robocopy.

Comment: What are the source and destination file systems? NTFS? Are the drives internal, networked, USB, ...?

Comment: And which version of Window 7 is it, e.g. professional, home, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Total Commander.  It was able to copy the 1.6TB of files that windows explorer could not handle, and it copied the files "on its own" instead of just asking windows explorer to copy them.

I have seen TeraCopy in action and I suspect it would have been a good candidate also, as it does its own file operations.

Although I am certainly open to using the command line, I don't think there is any evidence that the problem is directly related to whether or not a GUI is used.

I set this as the "answer" because that is what I used, feel free to upvote any answer that names a program you know does its own file operations.

Comment: Just to note that Robocopy uses it's own copying methods and can restart files mid-copy (use /Z option). Robocopy also handles paths longer than 256 characters long (which Explorer doesn't). Just because it's run from the command line, doesn't exclude it from being a program in its own right. Glad you found a good alternative to Explorer - I might give Total Commander a try myself.

Comment: There can be no doubt that some of the most 'serious' (in a good way) programs are run from the command line.

Comment: Another GUI solution, a bit cheaper than Total Commander: Beyond Compare (https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_editions). I have been using it for some years for folder comparisons and backups.

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments, don't use the Windows Explorer GUI.

A couple of good options are Robocopy (command line tool built into Windows since Vista), or [Teracopy](http://codesector.com/teracopy) which is a nice GUI tool that does fast copies of lots of files.

For info on how to use Robocopy, see this answer to a previous question (for a different issue, but valid to your case nonetheless) - https://superuser.com/a/349556/36510