# Logging files that are unable to transfer in powershell

Tags: powershell, file-transfer, logging

I'm trying to log some files that are unable to transfer when I'm recursively copying over one folder to a different location. When I right click, copy, and paste the folder, I get an error message "The file name you specified is not valid or too long". on some of the files.

Then I tried to use PowerShell to log the file names that are unable to transfer, but I get the message "Copy-Item : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

This is the PowerShell script that I am using:

```
$skippedFiles = @()
   
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Recurse

    foreach ($item in $items) {
         $destinationItemPath = Join-Path $destinationPath $item.FullName.Substring($sourcePath.Length + 1)
         if (Test-Path $destinationItemPath) {
              $skippedFiles += "Destination file already exists: $($item.FullName)"
              } elseif ($item.Name.Length -gt 255) {
                   $skippedFiles += "File name too long: $($item.FullName)"
              } else {
                   Copy-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination $destinationItemPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
              }
    }

$skippedFiles | Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath
```

Comment: if you want custom logging of errors that were caused by any failure, I'd recommend a try-catch. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-exceptions?view=powershell-7.4#trycatch

Answer (score 0):

This does not exactly answer your question, but shows ways *to work around* long filenames.

- If copying to a file system that supports long filenames, such as NTFS, [enable long filenames/paths](https://superuser.com/questions/1119883/windows-10-enable-ntfs-long-paths-policy-option-missing): In Regedit, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]` and create or edit Value DWORD `LongPathsEnabled`, setting it to 1.
- If the file system to which files are being copied *does not* support long filenames, such as FAT, [copy using the 8.3 format.](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html). E.G., for file `ALongFilename.txt`, use `xcopy /N *.txt .\destfldr`.

See also this answer on [long file path](https://superuser.com/questions/216704/how-to-copy-files-that-have-too-long-of-a-filepath-in-windows). In particular, [Robocopy](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html), part of Windows OS, will log any errors.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try out Robocopy later.